# Laravel - Same Session Over Multiples Projects - Using Same Database and Domain

Tags: php, laravel, session

I have two laravel 7 projects, which communicate in the same database.

serv1 : C:/xampp/htdocs/serv1/public

serv2:
C:/xampp/htdocs/serv2/public

I would like that , for example , when authenticating in which one of these applications , he would authenticate in both .

Comment: There's probably a few ways to do this given your restrictions. I suggest you read a bit more about single sign on (SSO) and try to implement the solution you think works best for your projects and ask a question if there are specific parts of the implementation you have issues with

Comment: Hello , I was actually seeing something about SSO and I came across Passport , I even did some tests with API and it worked perfectly , now I just managed to solve my situation by sharing the database , something very simple , replacing session storage file for database .